# Is there a way to do Inverse Kinematics on a non-standard skeleton?

Tags: animation, inverse-kinematics

So I'm trying to make new animations for a fairly old game. I've managed to get Inverse Kinematics to work with the skeleton by stretching the bones to connect to each other, but I can't use the animation in-game Because the bones revert to their original orientation, which breaks the animation. Is it possible to set up inverse kinematics for a skeleton like this or do I need to do the poses by hand?

[image: Individual bones]

[image]

I have tried setting up inverse kinematics in multiple ways, such as adding new bones to connect the joints and trying that way, but it just seems to make the model distort rather than actually work as an animation tool. In-game, the skeleton reverts to the old form and distorts the animation.

[image: Ik skeleton]

[image: Failed paste pose]